# Scroll to div by div with only one scroll, of divs that already scroll over each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made my divs scroll over each other, without them scrolling upwards out of the screen, from example (here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtyus/1/) ).

```js
(function($){
    /* Store the original positions */
    var d1 = $('.one');
    var d1orgtop = d1.position().top;
    var d2 = $('.two');
    var d2orgtop = d2.position().top;
    var d3 = $('.three');
    var d3orgtop = d3.position().top;
    var d4 = $('.four');
    var d4orgtop = d4.position().top;
    
    /* respond to the scroll event */
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        /* get the current scroll position */
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();

        /* change classes based on section positions */
        if (st >= d1orgtop) {
            d1.addClass('latched');
        } else {
            d1.removeClass('latched');
        }
        if (st >= d2orgtop) {
            d2.addClass('latched');
        } else {
            d2.removeClass('latched');
        }
        if (st >= d3orgtop) {
            d3.addClass('latched');
        } else {
            d3.removeClass('latched');
        }
        if (st >= d4orgtop) {
            d4.addClass('latched');
        } else {
            d4.removeClass('latched');
        }
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
.spacer {
    width: 0;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
     clear: both;
}
.one { background:red; width: 100%; height: 600px; position: relative; float: left; }
.two { background: blue; width: 100%; height: 600px; position: relative; float: left; }
.three { background: green; width: 100%; height: 600px; position: relative; float: left; }
.four { background: yellow; width: 100%; height: 600px; position: relative; float: left; }
.latched { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 8px; right: 8px; width: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1. Items that are not in fixed position * latched * scroll normally -->
<!-- 2. Items that go above the scroll position are given .latched -->
<!-- 3. If they scroll down again, they lose .latched -->
<!-- 4. div.spacer included to pad out space when content sections become latched -->

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="one">
    <h2>ONE</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

    <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="two">
    <h2>TWO</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

    <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="three">
    <h2>THREE</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

    <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="four">
    <h2>FOUR</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

    <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Now i want to scroll from div to div with only one scroll (scrolling from section to section)- see example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamikazefish/t6LLybx8/201/). while still maintianing the animated effect of one div scrolling over the other div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to modify your setup a bit. I put your divs into an array and then modified your code so that it kept track of target div for the scroll event. You'll also need to ignore the scroll events generated when you scroll to your element as well. The code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32917492/6106614) helped in that regard.

Here's your updated code (which also maintains the div-fixing effect):

```js
(function($) {
  var prevScroll = 0; //stores last successful scroll
  var scrollIdx = 0; //current index in your div array
  //array that contains the div object and original offset from the top to handle the animation
  var divs = [{
    div: $('.one'),
    top: $('.one').position().top
  }, {
    div: $('.two'),
    top: $('.two').position().top
  }, {
    div: $('.three'),
    top: $('.three').position().top
  }, {
    div: $('.four'),
    top: $('.four').position().top
  }];
  var scrollDestination = -1; //stores the target div's offset 

  // handles div fixing as the scroll transitions from one div to the next
  function setLatch(st) {
    divs.forEach(function(divObj) {
      if (st >= divObj.top) {
        divObj.div.addClass('latched');
      } else {
        divObj.div.removeClass('latched');
      }
    })
  }

  /* respond to the scroll event */
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    /* get the current scroll position */
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollDir = 0;

    //reset the latch as the scroll occurs
    setLatch(st);

    // check the state of the scroll event
    if (scrollDestination == -1) { //we're done scrolling
      //noop
    } else if (st != scrollDestination) { //we're still scrolling, ignore
      return;
    } else if (st == scrollDestination) { //we're done, but ignore this final scroll event
      scrollDestination = -1;
      prevScroll = st;
      return;
    }

    //determine the direction of the scroll;
    if (st > prevScroll) {
      scrollDir = 1;
    } else {
      scrollDir = -1;
    }

    if (scrollIdx + scrollDir == divs.length || scrollIdx + scrollDir < 0) {
      //do nothing bu update the prevScroll so we can accurately 
      //capture the direction the next time around
      prevScroll = st;
      return;
    }

    scrollIdx += scrollDir;
    //record the destination of the next div
    scrollDestination = divs[scrollIdx].top;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: divs[scrollIdx].top
    }, {
      duration: 1000
    });

  });

})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
.spacer {
  width: 0;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.one {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.two {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.three {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.four {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.latched {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1. Items that are not in fixed position * latched * scroll normally -->
<!-- 2. Items that go above the scroll position are given .latched -->
<!-- 3. If they scroll down again, they lose .latched -->
<!-- 4. div.spacer included to pad out space when content sections become latched -->

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="one">
  <h2>ONE</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat
    ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum
    mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec
    erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

  <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla
    mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="two">
  <h2>TWO</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat
    ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum
    mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec
    erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

  <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla
    mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="three">
  <h2>THREE</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat
    ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum
    mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec
    erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

  <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla
    mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="four">
  <h2>FOUR</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec lacus risus, eu sagittis felis. Praesent in feugiat elit. Pellentesque sem turpis, ornare et porttitor quis, placerat sit amet lacus. Fusce in purus sit amet sapien vestibulum volutpat
    ac at velit. Donec vel libero risus. Aliquam aliquet arcu vel justo molestie euismod. Suspendisse lorem massa, venenatis non congue a, commodo et nunc. Phasellus rhoncus, arcu a tristique adipiscing, mi dolor ullamcorper lacus, vel adipiscing ipsum
    mi ut augue. Pellentesque rhoncus dapibus tellus. Proin nec ante vel quam posuere mollis non vitae sem. Praesent hendrerit urna ac nisl consequat placerat. Ut placerat sollicitudin cursus. Curabitur orci magna, rhoncus et tempor non, volutpat nec
    erat. Sed ultrices ornare volutpat.</p>

  <p>Nunc imperdiet felis a purus feugiat vel euismod urna tristique. Maecenas sit amet felis tincidunt nulla tincidunt convallis nec eu purus. Donec auctor mauris non nisi rutrum euismod. Donec vehicula ipsum sit amet enim viverra sit amet commodo nulla
    mollis. Maecenas iaculis tincidunt quam et adipiscing. Vivamus eleifend nulla lobortis augue ultrices porta. Ut ut turpis dui, in vehicula nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Comment: On the first code snippet see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtyus/1/), one div is fixed, while the other div comes to slide on top of the fixed div, this is a major part of the snippet. but this your code disables that effect and only makes it move from div to div with one scroll. I can't accept it because it doesn't answer my question yet, but its one step further. thanks

Comment: I took the liberty to add your js code snippet to the original code, and when scrolling down, it works exactly how i want, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duyknL3n/), but when you try to scroll up, it doesn't work at all. the question now is, how to make it scroll back up in this manner. that would be the answer, thanks

Comment: Yep, I totally flubbed that, sorry. I went ahead and cleaned up and fixed my example to include your original effect as well as fix it so that it achieves the effect when you scroll back up.

Comment: Awesome! it totally worked. Thank you. This is the right answer)