# How to replace the default mouse scroll behavior by moving to each div tag each time the mouse scrolls up or down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many div tags displayed as columns, the height of each div is dynamically and less than the height inside the window. I want to scroll down the window the next div and in the middle of the window, similarly when the mouse scrolls up, the window will roll up the div above

Comment: Can you please include the relevant source code and your attempt to achieve your goal. Thank you.

Comment: This is my code, but I have no solution for mouse wheel events
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/880669/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library available online;
https://github.com/wtm/jquery.snapscroll

Or if you want to manually program it, here's a reference;
[Prevent triggering a scroll event by an animated scrollTop when using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874176/prevent-triggering-a-scroll-event-by-an-animated-scrolltop-when-using-jquery)